# How to implement Map and add element to map for manager & employee

Tags: java

I am new to java, learning [Map from java oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html),it says

What happens when you start mixing keys and values in the same bulk operation? Suppose you have a `Map`, managers, that maps each employee in a company to the employee's manager. We'll be deliberately vague about the types of the key and the value objects. It doesn't matter, as long as they're the same. Now suppose you want to know who all the "individual contributors" (or nonmanagers) are. The following snippet tells you exactly what you want to know.

```
Set<Employee> individualContributors = new HashSet<Employee>(managers.keySet());
individualContributors.removeAll(managers.values());
```

I am trying to code for above query,but i am not able to implement class `Manager` and `Employee` and its relation and put in a map and fetch `managers.values()`? Can someone give me example template for creating classes for above query with example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, the types for the managers and other employees are irrelevent.  The managerial relationships between them are managed using the "managers" map.  For example, you could set up the map using strings with code like this:

```
Map<String> managers = new HashMap<>();
managers.put("SoftwareEngineer1", "SoftwareEngineeringTeamManager");
managers.put("SoftwareEngineer2", "SoftwareEngineeringTeamManager");
managers.put("SoftwareEngineeringTeamManager", "MidLevelManager");
managers.put("MidLevelManager", "Executive");
managers.put("Executive", null);
```

This sets up two software engineers managed by a software engineer team manager, who is in turn managed by some mid level manager, who is in turn managed by some executive, who is managed by no one.  The keyset in the map is

```
["SoftwareEngineer1", "SoftwareEngineer2", "SoftwareEngineeringTeamManager", "MidLevelManager", "Executive"]
```

And the values are

```
["SoftwareEngineeringTeamManager", "MidLevelManager", "Executive", null]
```

In the code sample you posted, the values are subtracted from the key set, so you end up with

```
["SoftwareEngineer1", "SoftwareEngineer2"]
```

These are the individual contributors you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks  Todd Dunlap